# Flutter - how to prevent an app being closed by user on IpadPro (iPadOs 17)

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, ipad, ipados

I'm developing a tablet application for a cafe. The application is for commercial use only and will not be published on the app store. This is an application for the user to place an order, such as kiosks at McDonald's or KFS. I want the user to have no way to minimize or close this application. I want to make a dialog box where you need to enter a password to close it. How can i do this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwqQc.png)

Also, please tell me how to remove the three dots at the top that change the appearance of the screen and how to remove home indicator at the bottom (that black stick)

Comment: I have no experience with it myself, but I believe this is not the app itself that controls this. It's the device that does it. I believe it's often called Kiosk mode. Googling that might help you find how to do it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.